# Tooltip location in swing

Tags: java, swing, location, tooltip, jlist

I want to show tooltip for the elements in JList. I use `setToolTipText(str)` for that. What I want is that tool tip should be displayed at the right side of that element. I use `getToolTipLocation(mouseEvent)` but can't get desired result. How can I do this?

---

**Update**

My list class:-

```
public class MyList extends JList {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2170990919011800182L;

    DefaultListModel model;

    public MyList(DefaultListModel model){
        super(model);
        this.model = model;
    }

    public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e) {
        return new Point(75, locationToIndex(e.getPoint()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getNextMatch(String prefix, int startIndex, Position.Bias bias) {
        if (prefix == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'prefix' must not be"
                    + " null.");
        if (startIndex < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'startIndex' must not"
                    + " be less than zero.");

        if (startIndex >= model.getSize())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'startIndex' must not"
                    + " be greater than the number of"
                    + " elements.");

        int result = -1;
        int current = startIndex;
        int delta = -1;
        int itemCount = model.getSize();
        boolean finished = false;
        prefix = prefix.toUpperCase();

        if (bias == Position.Bias.Forward)
            delta = 1;
        while (!finished)
        {
            String itemStr = ((User) model.getElementAt(current)).getName().toString().toUpperCase();
            if (itemStr.indexOf(prefix)!=-1)
                return current;
            current = (current + delta);
            if (current == -1)
                current += itemCount;
            else
                current = current % itemCount;
            if(current == 0)
                finished = true;
            else                    
                finished = current == startIndex;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

My renderer class:-

```
public class MyRender extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer {

    //--class vars
    public MyRender(Atalk atalk) {
        //--initialize class var
    }

    @Override
    public JComponent getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        //-- put vales in class vars and add them in JPanel
        setToolTipText(user.getName()+"<br/>"user.getAddress());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Code where I declare lists.

```
JList[] list = new JList[5];
DefaultListModel[] model = new DefaultListModel[5];
model[0] = new DefaultListModel();
list[0] = new MyList(model[0]);
model[1] = new DefaultListModel();
list[1] = new MyList(model[0]);
model[2] = new DefaultListModel();
list[2] = new MyList(model[0]);
model[3] = new DefaultListModel();
list[3] = new MyList(model[0]);
model[4] = new DefaultListModel();
list[4] = new MyList(model[0]);
```

Comment: are you able to determine rectangle for JList Item in the visible ViewPort (from JScrollPane)

Comment: @mKorbel: how to determine that?

Comment: @Harry Joy : did you gone through my answer :)

Comment: @Damodar: yes I did but can't get it. Actually I know all this things what I don't know is how to put them together to get desired result. See the edit in question.

Comment: hmmm, maybe (and put together your last threads) would be better to add MouseMotionListener for JList (Couponds JComponents), then look for some RolloverSupport (determine what JComponets is under MouseCursor) and HashMap for ToolTip's text, and this ToolTip is very really very strange Component

Comment: @mKorbel , @Damodar : see update in my question.

Comment: @Harry Joy really no idea, because there is contructor inside Renderer, nearest to the correct way is Rob's answer

Comment: @mKorbel: there is no answer from Rob.

Answer (score 2):

Post your http://sscce.org when you have a problem. 2 lines of code doesn't show us what you are doing.

Here is a simple SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ListToolTip extends JFrame
{
    public ListToolTip()
    {
        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
        model.addElement("one");
        model.addElement("two");
        model.addElement("three");
        model.addElement("four");
        model.addElement("five");
        model.addElement("six");
        model.addElement("seven");
        model.addElement("eight");
        model.addElement("nine");
        model.addElement("ten");

        JList list = new JList( model )
        {
            public String getToolTipText( MouseEvent e )
            {
                int row = locationToIndex( e.getPoint() );
                Object o = getModel().getElementAt(row);
                return o.toString();
            }

            public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e)
            {
                int row = locationToIndex( e.getPoint() );
                Rectangle r = getCellBounds(row, row);
                return new Point(r.width, r.y);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( list );
        getContentPane().add( scrollPane );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ListToolTip frame = new ListToolTip();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setSize(400, 100);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Harry Joy, Did you read my comment? You have NOT posted a SSCCE. Your update means nothing to me. I gave you working code. If it doesn't do exactly what you want then customize it to meet your requirements.